# "Enable Wifi" on Xubuntu 15.04 Dell Inspiron 1564

Tags: networking, 15.04, xubuntu

I am a new Linux user and I've put xubuntu 15.04 on my laptop and the wifi isn't working (seems to be a common problem). I'm running this same distribution in a virtual box on my office computer and it works fine there. Also the wifi works if I boot my laptop to Windows. I've tried almost everything that I've read about and nothing is working.

Specifically I can't see "enable wireless" in the networking drop down.

Note: `sudo rfkill list all` doesn't output anything in my terminal which has made it hard to follow through with any tips that begin with that.

the 'lspci' output is here:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 12)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 12)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

Comment: What's the model of that card?

Comment: I'm not sure how to find something like that out? Also, what card are you talking about?
I also actually uninstalled 15.04 because I heard that 14.04 is more stable and doesn't have the wireless problems; but I'm actually having the exact same problem with 14.04

Comment: The WiFi card, sorry. Run `lspci` and [edit] the output into your question.

Comment: OK, I ran that and copied the output to the question.

Comment: Yep. You have Broadcom. Hang on, I need to get the link.

Comment: It automatically scrolls to the second answer, which is what you need: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers#38700

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the best linux wifi tutorials out there:

https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/374514-control-wireless-on-the-linux-desktop-with-these-tools

Comment: Two things. One: Link-only answers are not allowed. Two: the assumption in that article directly contradicts this question. It "assumes" that the user has a WiFi card working in Ubuntu, which Nic does not.

Answer (score 0):

yes. It is because your OS in your virtualbox doesnt have hardware of its own and the network card gives you a few options to choose from. Choose bridged network in your virtualbox settings for your OS and restart your virtual OS. And check your browser.

It does not show you a wireless connection but is connected internally as Ethernet.

Comment: No, he's saying the VM works fine, but the same Ubuntu version on that laptop _not_ in a VM doesn't recognize the card.

Comment: Yes that is because the OS doesnt its  have own hardware. And it forms a bridged connection to lan drivers through ethernet. And similarly the other hardware too.

Comment: details are given in detail in 6.5 chapter in this link.


https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Comment: The question isn't about the virtual machine. It's about a native OS where Wi-Fi isn't working when it should be. The virtual machine is just in the question as detail.

Comment: oh you are right, my bad. does that mean he dual boot his computer? and the wifi in the linux isnt working?

Comment: Yes. It works in Windows, but in Ubuntu the card isn't recognized.

Comment: Yes that is correct; my windows side runs just fine (if not but a little bit slow), but there is no 'enable wireless' when I boot to xubuntu.

Comment: Then you probably dont have the drivers compatible to ubuntu.

Comment: @Anand Ubuntu drivers don't work the same way as they do in Windows. If the WiFi doesn't work out of the box, then it's either a Broadcom, which has an easy fix, or there's something else wrong. There's always something available to make it work.

Comment: ya exactly that is why some drivers compatible to ubuntu have to be downloaded for different systems right?